# Custom validation fails

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

In my Grails 3.1.11 app I have a domain class

```
class Ability {

  String valueTypeName

  static constraints = {
    valueTypeName validator:{ val, obj, errors ->
      println val
      errors.rejectValue 'valueTypeName', 'err'
      return 'default.invalid.validator.message'
    }
  }
}
```

and scaffolded controller & views:

```
class AbilityController {
  static scaffold = Ability
}
```

Upon saving / updating, I can see println output in the console, but the object is never rejected... I tried returning false, but it remains the same.
Rejecting the value explicitely helps only by inserting.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you calling `rejectValue`?

Comment: I wanted to make sure, that nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the scaffolding.  See https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/issues/24

Note that validation is not failing.  The validation works.  The update really isn't sent to the database.  The problem is that the scaffolding shows a view that suggests that the update was made, but it wasn't.

Comment: so, you mean, that if I do `grails generate-all Ability`, it should be fine?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  I don't think the generated controller has the same bug as the dynamic one.